# Identifying an old flash game - 6x6 board, stacking tiles, possibly called "automatons"

Tags: identify-this-game

I am trying to find a two-player tile placement strategy board game that I played 15–20 years ago on a now-defunct Flash game aggregator website. I believe the name of the page was "Automatons", but I have had no luck finding any record of this game's existence outside of my memory. I would love to find this game again, either digitally or in a hard copy (if one ever existed).

## The board

The board was a 6x6 grid, if I recall correctly, with a 3D profile as indicated by the image below. The 16 center tiles were at "ground level", the edges were elevated by one step, and the corners by two steps.

## The rules

Two opposing players, Black and White, take turn placing tiles on the board. The tiles are square, slightly smaller in length and width than the board squares, and of thickness equal to the step height of the board; they are colored either Black or White but have no other marking features. Tiles can be placed on empty squares or stacked on top of other tiles of the same color.

When a stack reaches the height of four tiles (including the board steps—so three tiles on the edges or two tiles at the corners), it "pops", and the tiles in the stack are placed on the surrounding board squares. Popped tiles are placed on top of any stacks that may already be there. If Player A's popped tiles are placed on one of Player B's stacks, Player A captures the stack and replaces the tiles with ones of the appropriate color. In addition, pops can trigger further pops, cascading across the board.

If I remember correctly, a player wins when the other player has no tiles left on the board.

Does anyone else remember this game? Was it ever published physically? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Image of how I remember the board.]

Comment: Do you have any indication that there is a physical version of this game?

Comment: No indication, no, but I strongly suspect that it was based on a physical version because it so nicely translates to physical pieces and a board.

Comment: I remember a game with nearly identical rules but with blobby amoeba theme. You could grow a blob or start a new blob (equivalent to placing a tile in your version), and when the blob got to a certain size  (4, say, but it may be been 3), it split /divided and added on bit to each of the neighboring squares, converting their color if there was already an opposing blob there. Can't find anything specific on that now, though, sorry.